# Windowed Rendering Different Adapter

Tags: directx-11, sharpdx

I have a laptop with two adapters - An Intel and a NVIDIA. I'm running Windows 10 and there is no option in the Bios for turning off the embedded Intel adapter. I can specify to use the NVIDIA adapter for specific applications, or as the default for all Direct3D device creation. When I use the Intel adapter (which is the fixed adapter for the Windows Desktop) my 3D application in windowed mode works fine.

If I change the NVIDIA global setting to force the NVIDIA adapter for all Direct3D devices, or change my code to select the NVIDIA adapter, the code executes without any errors (I have DirectX Debug device attached) but nothing gets rendered in my window.

I believe that it is not possible to have a Windowed swapchain output attached to an Adapter that isn't the adapter used by the Windows desktop, but I have never seen this made explicit.

This means on a laptop using an embedded hardware adapter for the Windows desktop I cannot make use of the more powerful NVIDIA adapter in a Window and will have to use full-screen mode.

Can anyone confirm this, or suggest a device creation method that successfully allows me to address the second adapter in a Window ?

For clarity my device creation code is;

```
   private static void initializeDirect3DGraphicsDevice(System.Windows.Forms.Control winFormsControl, out Device device, out SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain sc)
    {
        SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription destination = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            ModeDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.ModeDescription(
                winFormsControl.ClientSize.Width,
                winFormsControl.ClientSize.Height,
                new SharpDX.DXGI.Rational(60, 1),
                SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            IsWindowed = true,
            OutputHandle = winFormsControl.Handle,
            SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
            SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.Discard,
            Usage = SharpDX.DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        using (SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1 factory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1())
        {
            // Pick the adapter with teh best video memory allocation - this is the NVIDIA adapter
            List<SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter> adapters = factory.Adapters.OrderBy(item => (long)item.Description.DedicatedVideoMemory).Reverse().ToList();
            SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter bestAdapter = adapters.First();

            foreach(SharpDX.DXGI.Output output in bestAdapter.Outputs)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Adapter " + bestAdapter.Description.Description.Substring(0,20) + " output " + output.Description.DeviceName);
            }

            device = new Device(bestAdapter, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);
            // Uncomment the below to allow the NVIDIA control panel to select the adapter for me.
            //device = new Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);
            sc = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain(factory, device, destination);
            factory.MakeWindowAssociation(winFormsControl.Handle, SharpDX.DXGI.WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device created with feature level " + device.FeatureLevel + " on adapter " + bestAdapter.Description.Description.Substring(0, 20));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The proprietary technology NVIDIA uses to manage both an Intel Integrated device and a NVIDIA discrete part is known as [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html). AMD has a simliar technology they call PowerXpress. They both play tricks with the default Direct3D device in the driver to control this behavior, which can be a bit strange to cope with as a developer.

> The hardware solution for these 'hybrid graphics' devices deal with the issue of merging the scanout from both GPUs so the monitor is always attached to just a single device.

The user can always choose to force an application to use one or the other through the control panel, which is the best user experience. The problem is that the default is often not a good choice for games. The solution for Win32 classic desktop apps it to put a 'magic export' into your EXE that the NVIDIA/AMD software will use to pick a default for an application not in the database:

```
// Indicates to hybrid graphics systems to prefer the discrete part by default
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```

The other option is to not use the default adapter when creating the device and explicitly enumerate them. This should work, but means that the user no longer has a way to easily change which device is being used. For example enumeration code, see [DeviceResources](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) and the `GetHardwareAdapter` method in particular. The drivers mess around with the enumeration as I note above, so the 'magic export' is probably the best general solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately I already have used the adapter enumeration and explicitly picked the NVIDIA adapter, and also tried using the NVIDIA control panel to default to their adapter for all new Direct3D Device creations. I suspect because I'm targetting a windowed swapchain (not a full screen) and that Windows is already using the Intel adapter (you cannot change that) the only valid config is to use the Intel adapter. I think I need to alter my code to make it fullscreen to use your suggested method. I've updated with my device creation code for clarity.